# Add and start/stop containers with docker-compose dynamically

Tags: docker

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file with some services, like web server, database and nginx. However, beside these services that are always up, I need a number of instances of some other service which I want to dynamically create then start and stop.

For example, I have a small service that listens on some port and returns some value back when requested. I need 300 instances of this service running as containers which can then start and stop.

The number is not fixed and I want to be able to have 0-300 instances to be up on demand via docker tools/stack.

How can I do this in a better way? Is swarm something that can help here?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is something one can achieve with an orchestrator.

Nowadays, [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) is the trend. However, it is complicated to set up and the learning curve is steep compared to [Docker Swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/). If you're already familiar with Docker, using Docker Swarm is straightforward.

Suppose your `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
services:
  webserver:
    ...
  database:
    ...
  nginx:
    ...
  small-service:
    deploy:
      replicas: 6
    volumes:
      - "/path/for/task/{{.Task.Slot}}:/data"
```

You have your webserver, database, nginx, and your small service. Note that you can decide how many replicas (or task, as it's called in Docker Swarm) of a service you want to have in the `docker-compose.yml` file. More options under `deploy` can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/deploy/).

Another interesting feature, as you asked for, is mounting different volumes for different tasks. By using `.Task.Slot` in the path, each task will mount their data to different locations in the host machine. Please check [this documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#create-services-using-templates) to see which other options are available besides `.Task.Slot`.

To deploy this using Docker Swarm, simply run this command:

```
docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml <your-stack-name>
```

Then, besides other services, you will have 6 replicas of your `small-service` running.

At some point, you might want to change the number of replicas to 100. To do that, use the [`scale`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/scale-service/) function:

```
docker service scale small-service=100
```

Or if you want to stop that service, [`rm`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/delete-service/) is the way to go.

```
docker service rm small-service
```

Comment: I tried this and it looks promising. Though, when I start a new instance with `scale` or even at very start, can I pass different params to each instance? For example, to keep data of each instance in its own separate folder on the host machine?

Comment: Yes, you can. Please check my updated answer.